# Scrapy/Python web table missing closing TR / TD Tags

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm redoing a data scraping project. There's a website with a table of data that is missing most or all of the closing TR and TD tags. When I first did the project with JS, I just copied the site and then split the data into arrays of rows when it encountered a new "" tag.

I want to try to rebuild this project using python/scrapy and just wondering if there was an easier way to access the data using selectors. Also I'm a little confused how to split the data when the response.data.split(') doesn't work.

Comment: There are multiple ways of selecting a part of site/page for crawling it, in python for e.g. using `selectors`,`xpath`,`by text name`,`tag` etc.

Comment: @the.salman.a my problem is when I select the tr tag for example, it thinks the entire table is one tr tag because there is no closing tag. and every td is a child element. even though there is only 7 columns per row, every td is named as a child element of the first tr.

Comment: Can you give me URL of the page or an screenshot of the same. May be I can help.

Comment: Sure. I'm trying to get data from this page http://killedbypolice.net/

Comment: right now I worked out that I could do something like

`rows = re.split('<tr>', str(response.body), flags=re.IGNORECASE)
            for row in rows:
                item = re.split('<td>', row,
                                flags=re.IGNORECASE)
                data.append(item)`

which gets me my basic data that I need to parse, but yeah if there was another way that'd be cool too. @the.salman.a

Comment: Did you try using selectors, I saw the page and It's unique for each Cell. And if you get data using selector you wouldn't have to use `split` and all. You'd need to spent a little time but you'll get it eventually.

Comment: Yeah I tried using selectorgadget on the page to select only the rows i wanted or the columns I wanted, but it seemed like it would be rather challenging. I guess I'll just stick with my splitting for now, haha it's way simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem . you can use beautyfulsoup's select method for successfully query. I make a demo code for you. hope this will help you.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://killedbypolice.net/';
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
soup.select('table tr')
print(soup.select('table')[0])
```